# Collecting and Making ACH Payments

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, credit-card, payment-processing, payment-services

We're creating a platform with PHP back-end where a customer will be able to purchase a service through the platform with their credit card or linked checking account. The platform will collect the payment, take out their fee and pass the remainder on to the business fulfilling the customer's order. The payment will be deposited directly into the fulfilling company's checking account.

I know PayPal offers their Advanced Payments and Payment Pro solutions to address this, but we're trying to identify a payment platform that will allow this to be done with direct ACH debits/payments.

We've researched the following which do not offer a solution to this use case:

- https://samurai.feefighters.com
- authorize.net
- http://www.firstdata.com/global-selector.html
- stripe.com

Anyone know of a solution that will address this need? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [Balanced](https://www.balancedpayments.com). We process credit cards and ACH deposits.

Balanced also has an ACH debit API in the works, check out the spec and discussion over on the [Github repo](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-api/issues/milestones). The debits API will hopefully be live for production within a month.

Comment: Can you get in touch with me through my company site - digitalxbridge.com?

Comment: you should have been contacted last week via email, if not let me know and we'll follow up

Comment: I responded to Jareau and Manisha but have not heard back.